# Différence entre rivière et fleuve

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, géographie

Je sais qu'un fleuve est un cours d'eau qui se jette dans une mer, mais est-ce l'unique différence ?

Si une rivière a une grande quantité d'eau mais qu'elle ne se jette pas dans une mer, ne peut-elle pas être appelée fleuve ?

Comment: Qu'est-ce qui n'est pas clair dans les définitions du dictionnaire ?

Comment: Les définitions du Wiktionnaire paraissent contradictoires, et la définition théorique n'est pas toujours celle qui est appliquée en pratique.

Comment: [Rivière](https://www.aquaportail.com/definition-4558-riviere.html) et [fleuve](https://www.aquaportail.com/definition-4557-fleuve.html) en hydrologie. Une rivière se termine à un confluent, mais il y a des exceptions consacrées par l'usage (la [Seine](https://www.lyonne.fr/auxerre-89000/actualites/riviere-ou-fleuve-pourquoi-l-yonne-a-ete-detronee-par-la-seine_12727535/)).

Answer (score 5):

La distinction entre fleuve et rivière n'est effectivement pas basée principalement sur la taille, contrairement aux mots désignant les cours d'eau dans de nombreuses autres langues. Ainsi, on peut parler de “fleuve côtier” pour un petit cours d'eau qui se jette dans la mer. C'est généralement ce qu'on apprend à l'école en France et c'est ce que réflètent les définitions des dictionnaires.

Il y a cependant quelques exceptions comme l'Okavango ou le Jourdain, qu'on appelle tout de même “fleuves” bien qu'ils n'atteignent jamais d'océan. Il y a aussi des fleuves côtiers qui portent le nom de “rivière”, notamment dans le Morbihan (rivière d'Étel, rivière de Pénerf).

Il peut donc y avoir un peu de flottement (peut-être plus fréquemment en appelant un petit fleuve “rivière” que l'inverse) mais ces usages risquent d'apparaître fautifs à de nombreux locuteurs.

Comment: En effet, [le  ruisseau du Moulin de Tohon](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5c/Billiers_port_Pen_Lan_rivi%C3%A8re_Saint-Eloi.JPG/560px-Billiers_port_Pen_Lan_rivi%C3%A8re_Saint-Eloi.JPG) est un fleuve, selon la définition du Larousse, alors que [la Marne](https://static.actu.fr/uploads/2019/04/25415-190430140630981-0.jpg) est une rivière. Mais qui les nomme ainsi ? Dans l'usage courant une rivière est un cours d'eau de moindre importance qui se jette ou non dans la mer.

Comment: @mins Je n'ai jamais entendu parler de la Marne comme d'un fleuve.

Comment: Dans la langue courante, on trouve pas mal d'exemples (2.400 recensés par Google), y compris [chez des gens éduqués](https://blogs.mediapart.fr/didier-martz/blog/091214/ainsi-va-le-monde-n-261-remonter-la-marne-avec-jean-paul-kauffmann) qui s'étonnent que ce soit le plus long fleuve qui prenne le nom de rivière. Et si le critère définissant qui est l'affluent n'est pas la longueur, mais le débit, et bien le [l'Yonne est un fleuve](https://www.lyonne.fr/auxerre-89000/actualites/riviere-ou-fleuve-pourquoi-l-yonne-a-ete-detronee-par-la-seine_12727535/) et la Seine une rivière.

Comment: @mins Je ne vois pas bien où vous voulez en venir. Ma réponse est en fait plus nuancée que cela mais l'article que vous citez n'est en aucun cas un usage du mot “fleuve” à propos d'un cours d'eau qui ne se jette pas dans la mer. Bien au contraire, il accepte la définition la plus académique du mot pour le revendiquer pour la Marne *jusqu'à la Manche*. Si l'auteur considérait que la Marne était un fleuve alors même qu'elle se jette dans la Seine, il n'aurait rien à dire...

Comment: J'ajoute des éléments à votre réponse, sans la remettre en cause.